# Is it a sin for promiscuous, unmarried women to have sex with many men?

Tags: women, sin, dharma-shastras, sex

As discussed in [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/31747/is-it-a-sin-to-have-sex-with-promiscuous-unmarried-women), many ancient Vedic scholars believe that the Vedas declare that it is not sinful for grihastha men to have sex with promiscuous, unmarried women.

This question is now asking whether it is sinful for promiscuous, unmarried women to have sex with multiple partners.

In the entire [Manusmriti](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi), nowhere is it explicitly stated that this is sinful for unmarried women. In verses that talk about "unchaste" women and unchastity being sinful, the unchastity is in regard to *married* women who have cheated on their husband, but since unmarried women do not have husbands, it follows that this injunction does not apply to them.

So is there any verse that states that it's sinful for unmarried girls to have sex with lots of men?

Comment: See the Apasthambha verse I added to my answer .. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/31763/4732

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/44325/if-karma-is-real-then-is-rape-justified#comment138068_44325

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto What about that question? It has nothing to do with my question. That question is about rape....

Answer (score 4):

[Manu Smriti 4.220](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc200324.html) regards unchaste woman to be sinful. And, which is already evident to some of us. Due to promiscuity they have attained a sinful nature.

The verse does not mention whether it is about married or unmarried woman.

> पूयं चिकित्सकस्यान्नं पुंश्चल्यास्त्वन्नमिन्द्रियम् ।
>  विष्ठा
>   वार्धुषिकस्यान्नं शस्त्रविक्रयिणो मलम् ॥ २२० ॥
>
> pūyaṃ cikitsakasyānnaṃ puṃścalyāstvannamindriyam |
>  viṣṭhā
>   vārdhuṣikasyānnaṃ śastravikrayiṇo malam || 220 ||
>
> The food of the physician is pus; the food of the unchaste woman is
>   semen; the food of the usurer is ordure, and that of the dealer in
>   weapons is dirt.—(220.)

> many ancient Vedic scholars believe that the Vedas declare that it is
>   not sinful for grihastha men to have sex with promiscuous, unmarried
>   women.

This is not true at all. Apasthambha says in this regard:

> **It is a sin to engage in sexual intercourse with** a woman who has been married before, or **whom he has not married with the proper
>   rites**, or who belongs to a different class than he; 4and a son born
>   from their union undoubtedly participates in their sin.
>
> *Apasthambha Dharma Sutras 2.13-3,4*

Comment: "the food of the unchaste woman is semen" - This verse is saying that it is sinful to accept their food, not that it is a sin for them to be unchaste. But the Apastamba verse is valid.

Comment: Accepting food from sinful persons is what the scriptures censure .. so why are you confused? @Ikshvaku